# Simple java program "Hello World!" not working after installing Android plugins in the eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, eclipse-plugin

Recently I installed Android plugins in Eclipse.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit and having **jre6** installed

Every thing for Java was fine before this, but after installing plugins I created simple Java program to see if it works fine!

Below is my "Hello World!" program

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
}
```

On running this program nothing is getting printed.

I have touched nothing except installing Android plugins in Eclipse,
and above code is running fine with Windows Console.

when i installed Android plugins i was using **JDK 1.7** but then on searching for solution for my problem I came to know that **Android** needs **JDK 1.6** so i installed **JRE6**
but the result stood same nothing helped so i Removed all the **JDKs and JREs** from my Windows and installed fresh **JRE6** for this problem despite of not being related with **JAVA** but then all the projects in my Workspace got unbounded from the **JDK 1.7**.

On trying to rebind the JRE i was getting below error
[image]

so I created new Workspace and the above JRE problem got solved but still in new Workspace the "Hello World!" program is not running.

I have tried all the things with Environment Variables but nothing is helping

Below links suggested some solutions

1. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/913523/
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/186986/eclipse-has-multiple-issues-after-jre-6-openjdk-upgrade
3. http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/156204/530834/

Most of the solutions are for **Linux and OpenJDK** and are not helpful for me as well.

Please help me out here, I don't want to install new instance of Eclipse if there is a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Below is part of the .metadata/.log file for both newly created Workspace and old one.
The original one is very big so i am putting some initial lines.

```
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.debug.ui 4 120 2013-06-19 16:05:42.744
!MESSAGE Error logged from Debug UI: 
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.launchConfigurations.JavaApplicationLaunchShortcut.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getDelegate(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getLaunchConfigurations(LaunchShortcutExtension.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.getParticipatingLaunchConfigurations(LaunchingResourceManager.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.getLabel(LaunchingResourceManager.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager.computeLabels(LaunchingResourceManager.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.contextlaunching.LaunchingResourceManager$2.run(LaunchingResourceManager.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui (341).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at
```

Comment: I would recommend trying to compile a helloworld program from the command line and seeing if that works.  If it does you know you have a corrupt eclipse installation.  If it doesn't, you know something is up with your java installation.

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that the program works fine from the command line. So now I will have to get new instance of Eclipse now!

Comment: Trying doing just a repair on eclipse instead of a full install.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse is this?

Comment: @SaviourSelf It is Eclipse Juno.

Comment: @nkon How can i repair it? Please give me some hints.

Comment: You can go to the control panel and go to programs and features, select your application and select repair or change.

Comment: @nkon Since I haven't installed Eclipse Juno from installation file, so it could not be done this way. Is there any other way to repair it?

Comment: I think this article will help you.. http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t61566.html  Good lucK!

Comment: @nkon I tried all the solution suggested in the article you gave a link to. No one worked for me except last one, I will have to get new instance of the Eclipse as a solution.